# Read 50 images as each pixel matrix from a pool of 1000 images

Tags: python, image, loops, matrix

I have 1000 grayscale images with a dimension of 800x600 pixels.
Each pixel have a value beetween 0...255.

I want to pick out 50 images of this 1000 images.
Of this 50 images I want to find out the max. grayscale value (0...255).
From this I want to build only one new image with the max. grascale value (0...255).

At the end I wand to take each of the 1000 images and divide each pixel by the new image pixel and multiply with 255.

**I start with chose the first 50 picked images:**

```
from random import seed
from random import sample

# seed random number generator
seed(1)
# prepare a sequence
sequence = [i for i in range(1000)]
print(sequence)
# select a subset without replacement
subset = sample(sequence, 50)
                print("Chosed 50 random images: ", subset)
```

Then I start to read the images in a loop.
**Read out the max. pixel value from the 50 picked images:**

```
for i in range(0,49):
       for d in range(0, 599):
             for s in range(0, 799):
                      print("Chosed image: ", subset[i], "Chosed pixel (rundownstairs): ", d, "Chosed pixel (run sidewise): ", s )
```

But I have not idea to read the pixels in a matrix and make the mathematical matrix calculations.

Comment: Do you have a folder with those 1000 images?

Comment: Yes. It is: '/media/images/1.png' ... '1000.png'

Comment: Why do you want to do this please?

Comment: What is the point of this please? Is it some sort of academic learning exercise or just something you need to get done? If the latter, you can actually do it in 2-3 commands in the shell without writing any Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I don't have your images, I generated `n` random images.
I did an array with these images and found their coordinates with `max` value. Then I organized those indexes so that it can be read: 
With `listOfCordinates` you should be able to start doing operations with your pixels.
NOTE that I used numpy, I don't know if that's a problem.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob, os

os.chdir("C:/Users\iareval1\Documents\OCLASS\class_def") #your folder
n = 5 #Number oof images
img_arr = [] #array with images
n_nad_files = []

for i in range(0,n):
    n_nad_files.append(glob.glob("*.png")[np.random.randint(n)])

for file in n_nad_files: #set the file termination
    img = cv2.imread(file, 0)
    img_arr.append(img)



dim_x = img_arr[0].shape[0]
dim_y = img_arr[0].shape[1]

img_with_max = np.zeros((dim_x, dim_y))


cnt = 0
for image in img_arr:
    print("Max values in image " +  str(cnt))
    for x in range (0, dim_x):
        for y in range (0, dim_y):
            img_with_max[x][y] = max(img_with_max[x][y], image[x][y])
    cnt += 1
```

If you want to plot an image you can

```
plt.imshow(YOUR_IMAGE,cmap=cm.bone) #show your array with the selected colour
plt.show() #show the image
```

Comment: The 50 images was picked out of the 1000 images.

Comment: As it was already proposed, you could use `img = cv2.imread('image_file_path', 0)` .   probably the best solution, but you NEED openCV

Comment: I understand. But in the proposal above you create randomed images, but i want only to pick out 50 images out of the 1000 images.

Comment: Yes I know. I though that was the easy part :D give me a couple minutes I'll work on that

Comment: There you have `n` random images from your folder. And I generated `img_with_max` containing the max of all images in the sama pixel coordintes

Comment: You are surely not going to read and uncompress all 1,000 images into memory to only use 50 of them?

Comment: until img_with_max = np.zeros((dim_x, dim_y)) it is fine.

Comment: The 50 images are loaded as a one image array. 8-bit with pixel values beetween 0...255. Out of this 50 images i want the max. value of all pixels (pixel by pixel) and then build a new image from this. Until img_with_max = np.zeros((dim_x, dim_y)) is it right. But then i get ony a black white (0, 255) image. It can not be.

Comment: @Tommy it makes sense. From your random images the max value is very likely 255 . And all the pixels with lower values will be 0

Comment: It is also true that with my code you will have 1000 images in memory and then use only 50 . But I think there's enough information in the code to avoid that

Comment: @Ivan. The theoreticaly max. value is 255. But I can not belive that in each pixel is this 255. I want to have the max. value of this 50 images in a pixel. (pixel by pixel). the images are grayscale and the created image is black-white. if it not 255 then it is 0?

Comment: !!!! You mean the Max valley between the 50 images on each pixel? I thought the max value in each of the images! ... If that's the case,you can still use the second `for` cycle and update `img_with_max` at every iteration on each pixel. If the pixel value is higher than the current => update it

Comment: @Ivan Yes, that I mean. I think I must change this: img_with_max[cord[0]][cord[1]] = 255 ?

Comment: I judt edited the code to replace pixels in `img_with_max` with the current highest value. @MarkSetchell it won't load the 1000 only `n` images

Comment: @Ivan Your are my python god.

Answer (score 0):

For image processing I recommend you `opencv`, you have to install it. For reading an image in grayscale you can use this, you will get a `numpy` array:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np


img = cv2.imread('image_file_path', 0)
```

For finding the maximum value in an array you can use this:

```py
max_value = np.max(img)
```

And for applying mathematical operations to the entire array just do something like this:

```py
mod_img = img / max_value
```

Comment: OK. But i must save each pixel value in a matrix (50x800x600) and then find out the max. of each pixel of 50 image pixels.